# javascript float32Array push changes value

Tags: javascript, c#, float32

I recently find out some weird behaviour in JS, and i might need some insight on it.

i have a js script that i need to translate into C#.
now, in the JS i have:

values  = new Float32Array(n).fill(0) (fill(0) just fill the array with 0 values)
i compute several values, one is 0.48214292933260094 (that is stored in another Float32Array).

Now when i do a values.push() of this value, the value stored in the array is now 0.48214292526245117 which is close but not the same...

When doing the same thing in C#, the value stay the same (either as float, double or decimal).

Does anyone have a hint at why?
the discrepency appears around the 7th digit so i guess it has to do with floating point errors, yet i use Float32Array in the two objects....
(Further ahead in the code i filter the values depending if they are == 0, so that's creating divergence between JS and C#)

tried different type of data in C# (double,float,decimal), C# stay consistent when transfering value from one list to another. JS is not.
the weirdest part is that JS script works and C# don't...

Comment: The behavior you're observing is due to the inherent differences in how floating-point numbers are represented and handled in JavaScript and C#. These differences can lead to slight variations in the stored values, especially when you're working with very precise numbers.

Comment: Keep in mind that a 32-bit floating point number cannot represent values with the same precision as a normal 64-it floating point number.

Comment: @Jay IEEE floating point works the same way, if there are differences they stem from how the values are formatted for printing/display (turned into strings, in other words).

Comment: @Pointy i've red many of the question on that topic. It often has to do with translating or passing a value from one langage to another (C# -> js vis versa) via Json or whatever.
What i'm stunned by is that within a unique Js script the push() changes the value.
I can give a simplified version of the script if it helps.

Comment: @LChougrani putting a number in a Float32 array strips off literally half the bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> C# stay consistent when transfering value from one list to another.

No, you can try the following code in C#

```
// (double)(float)0.48214292933260094 = 0.48214292526245117
var v = new List<float> { (float)0.48214292933260094 };
Console.WriteLine((double)v[0]);
```

The result you got in JS is because `Float32Array` uses 32-bit to store numbers, while floating point numbers in JS are 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. i would not have thought of a double cast... that odd.